# How to join a table and then table inside table in mysqli?

Tags: join, mysqli

I have a table name

`deposite` with columns `deposite_id`, `assigncourse_id`

and `assigncourse` table with columns `assigncourse_id`, `std_id`, `course_id`

and two tables `std` and `course`

now i want to join `assigncourse` table from `deposite` table and then join with `std` and `course` table from `assigncourse` table, with mysqli query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM deposite d
JOIN (SELECT a.assigncourse_id
    FROM assigncourse a
    JOIN std t ON a.std_id = t.std_id
    JOIN course c ON a.course_id = c.course_id
) m ON d.assigncourse_id = m.assigncourse_id;
```

Comment: what is m here??

Comment: ‘m’ you can understand a table that queried by Subquery

Comment: any reference for more detailed answer to understand

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html，my answer ,its work?.